# Naming conventions for private hooks in packages using lthooks

Tags: latex3, naming, hooks

In some package, I use a lot of hooks (using the `lthooks` package) that are however not intended to be used as a hook by other packages / users.
Only certain code makes sense there, and I use hooks because throughout my package there is several places adding to these hooks, whilst also using the `\DeclareHookRule`, so this is very useful.

In the `lthooks` documentation, it is mentioned that the LaTeX kernel uses hooks like `\@kernel@before@...`, which is such a naming convention, but unfortunately does not support the useful `\DeclareHookRule` interface etc.

Is there some naming convention on how to name such hooks, like prefixing them with `__`or something?

Comment: The kernel hooks don't support the rule interface as it doesn't make much sense for internal code: The hook interface is quite fast but nevertheless it is more complex than simply adding code to a tl-var and so you are slowing down compilation without much gain as the rules are not needed if you have control over the code.

Comment: in my case, actually the user has control over the hook rules (customization, I provide a wrapper macro to set these), but not (directly) over the hook contents